# Repository pattern return element in only read

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I realized that if I call the SelectById method and then I modify the variable and commit, the changes are applied to the database, so the update method is totally useless.
I wanted to avoid doing such a thing, since anyone with access to the pattern Repository can modify variables without going through the update method.
What I want is to be able to return a variable that is "detached" from the database and if you were to commit the changes are not applied.
I was able to do this only in the following way, inside the selectByID, I create a new dataset and then do the dispose.

sensor repository constructor

```
       public SensorRepository(OramsContext _db, ILogger logger) : base(_db, logger)
        {
            _context = _db;
        }
```

Method with new context

```
        public override  Sensor? SelectByID(int id)
        {
            // new context
            var internaContext = _context;
            
             var query = (from x in internaContext.Sensor where x.SensorId == id select x).FirstOrDefault();
            
            //dispose after query
            internaContext.Dispose();
            
             if (query == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return query;
        }
```

if I do this, in case of changing the variable and then calling the Complete, the value is not updated

```
        using (UintOfWork uow = new UintOfWork())
        {
            Sensor? s =  uow.Sensors.SelectByID(10);
            if (s != null)
            {
                s.ReferenceIdFile = 100+i;
                int c = await uow.CompleteAsync();
            }


        }
```

This is a classic Select method found online, In this case, if I modify the variable and save without passing the update, the changes are saved in the DB.

```
        public override Sensor? SelectByID(int id)
        {

            return (from x in dbSet where x.SensorId == id select x).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

What I am wondering is if there is a better way to do as I did in the method with the new Context.

UPDATE

and if I had to put two contexts, one only view and the other for the action of update, insert and delete?

These are the two context variables

```
        private readonly OramsContext _context;


        private readonly OramsContext _contextView;
```

In the selectByID method I use the "view-only" context

```
        public async Task< Sensor?> SelectByIDAsync(int id)
        {
            return await (from x in _contextView.Sensor where x.SensorId == id select x).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

And in the Complate method,I invoke SaveChangese only on the other one

```
        public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Repo} CompleteAsync method error", typeof(UintOfWork));
                return 0;
            }

        }
```

Can this system have problems?

Comment: Don't use this code in the first place. A DbContext is *already* a Unit-of-Work and multi-entity repository. A DbSet is already a single-entity repository.  Your `SelectByID` *rolls back* the UoW when it disposes the DbContext. You didn't post what `CompleteAsync` does, but unless it calls `SaveChangesAsync`, nothing will be saved

Comment: If you don't want to persist changes to your object, don't call `SaveChangesAsync`. That's what commits the changes. That's how EF Core works.

Comment: `so the update method is totally useless.` yes, because all those "repository pattern" implementations are broken. `a classic Select method found online` no it's not, it's actualy a bug. If `SensorId` is the PK, `_context.Sensors.Find(id)` will load *and* cache the object. If you don't want that, `_context.Sensors.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.SensorID==id)` or `_context.Sensors.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.SensorID==id)`. It's a *good* idea to have separate DbContexts for reporting and modifications. This way you can disable tracking for the entire reporting DbContext

Comment: `var internaContext = _context;` doesn't create a new context. It uses the original, using a different variable. `internaContext.Dispose()` disposes the actual context object, discarding changes. Any subsequent attempt to use the context will result in an `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: Hi Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks for replay.  The problem of invoking the saveChanges is only if the user using the repository and doesn' t pay attention to the modification of the variable. certainly I am not going to invoke it in vain.  Can you recommend something instead of the Repository pattern? Maybe the ddd. what do you think about having two contexts inside the repository, one dedicated to obtaining the info and the other for deleting updates and inserts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.AsNoTracking()` which detaches the entity returned from your context. Any changes you make aren't tracked by the EF entitytracker.

```
return (from x in dbSet.AsNoTracking() where x.SensorId == id select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This just covers up the bug*s* in the code. There wouldn't be any need for this if the code didn't try to *save*  changes. `AsNoTracking()` is meant as a performance enhancement